# How to prevent Apache from continuing to evaluate rewrite rules after a match?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have, amongst others, the following rewrite rules in the .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
[1]    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
[2]    SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4

[3]    RewriteEngine on

[4]    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
[5]    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
[6]    RewriteRule ^ - [L]      
    ...
[7]    RewriteRule ^\/de\/Artikel-Kategorie-([a-zA-Z,-_]+)\.html$ /art-cat.php?plng=de [L]
[8]    RewriteRule ^\/de\/Artikel-Alle-Kategorien\.html$ /art-cat.php?plng=de [L,QSA]
[9]    RewriteRule ^\/en\/Articles-([a-zA-Z,-_]+)\.html$ /art-cat.php?plng=en [L]
[10]    RewriteRule ^Articles-([a-zA-Z,-_]+)\.html$ art-cat.php?plng=fr [L]

[11]    RewriteRule ^\/de\/Artikel-([a-zA-Z,-_]+)\.html$ /art-item.php?plng=de&c=$1 [L,QSA]
[12]    RewriteRule ^\/en\/Article-([a-zA-Z,-_]+)\.html$ /art-item.php?plng=en&c=$1 [L]
[13]    RewriteRule ^Article-([a-zA-Z,-_]+)\.html$ art-item.php?plng=fr&c=$1 [L]
    ...
```

When the URL http://dev.domain.com/de/Artikel-Alle-Kategorien.html is requested, the rule that gets applied is the one in line [11], although the rule in line [8] is an exact match.
The result is a list of error messages pertaining to script `art-item.php` whereas `art-cat.php` should be called:

```
Notice: Undefined index: code in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/dev/art-item.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/dev/art-item.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax ...
```

I've read through a couple of articles and other questions here on this subject but nothing I tried seems to work. I suspect that the problem is somehow related to the L flag, but I couldn't find a solution to apply to my case.

I'm a bit at a loss here. Can someone please point me into the right direction ?

Comment: Since you've numbered all the lines in the config file, could you reference those in the text of the question, too? I'm having trouble picking out what you mean by "the first of the second block".

Comment: You're right, sorry :-) Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip all the rules for files and directories first:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4

RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]    

RewriteRule ^de/Artikel-Alle-Kategorien\.html$ art-cat.php?plng=de [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^de/Artikel-Kategorie-([a-z,_-]+)\.html$ art-cat.php?plng=de&c=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^en/Articles?-([a-z,_-]+)\.html$ art-cat.php?plng=en&c=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^Articles?-([a-z,-_]+)\.html$ art-cat.php?plng=fr&c=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but it does not seem to have any impact at all. Can you please explain what the logic behind it is?

Comment: Just added the question so that the elements you are asking for are included. RE the comment line in your reply - sorry but I'm not very good at this, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by 'skip all files and directories' here.

Comment: I have added line numbers to the htaccess extract for clarification. The rule which should be applied is in line 8, the one that gets applied instead is in line 11. I think the order is correct. Re the hyphens, ok thanks, I'll correct that.

Comment: Tried your suggested solution for the .htaccess but the problem remains the same unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately no further help is possible with the vague information in comments.